# Tight triceps: should I rest or continue swimming?

Tags: swimming

For the past 3 days, I have been swimming very hard. Now, my triceps muscles have started to feel the pain. Rather than calling it pain, I would say, they are tightened up.

Should I continue swimming? Or should I rest for 1 or 2 days and wait for the triceps to loosen up. Normally, I swim every day.

Comment: Why don't you experiment?  Why don't you take a day off and gauge how you feel.  One day of rest isn't going to kill your performance...

Comment: Is doing your workout mainly with your legs an option? Let your arms have the workout off for the most part while focusing on kicks?

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc, thank you for the suggestion. I have rested today and going to workout tomorrow. I will let you know how I feel after that.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if the muscle feels better after ~10 minutes of exercise, it's ok to work it. If it still hurts, stop and rest.

Comment: Yeah, I know myself pretty good and I would try it even I'm not 100% OK. I can see one problem here: you've already paid for swimming pool (in case you son't have one 25m line in your basement :P) so in that case, as I wrote, I'd switch to hard leg workout + dolphin kick which need pretty much your core working too. For example now dolphin kick training is, let's say, 1/4 of my training. It's simply so big advantage after a roll that it's worth to train it really hard. And some pain in the arm is very good reason for doing it right now.

Comment: Of course there are no rolls on open water, triathlon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's really worth to **take a good rest**.

If there is a continual overload for particular muscles you are simply risking too much in long term sustainability. There is a risk of **microtrauma** here and you can damage your body. One day rest now can save you another week of training when you are back in a good fit.

I don't know your workout but I experience tired triceps mostly when swimming crawl. I'd suggest you to switch to a backstroke at least for a while. You should swim **the same distance by crawl and the same distance by backstroke to avoid disbalance**. It can be in one workout day or in one week for example 3 days crawl and 3 days backstroke.

If it's not a problem you can go out of water for two days and try for example **running** or go to the **gym** and focus on your **core** (which will be used while swimming too!).

It has been already suggested in comments: if you can't be without water just do great **leg workout** for this time and let your arms rest.

I hope I don't need to mention proper **warming up** before training and **stretching** after it.

P.S.: You can try a **massage** too.